# Getting the count of an iteration completion elixir

Tags: elixir

I have this code snippet

```
1..total_days |> Enum.reduce(start_date, fn _i, acc ->
  day_of_week = acc |> Calendar.Date.day_of_week_name
  rec_head = get_head_tail(schedule[day_of_week])
  rec_head |> Enum.each(fn(x) ->
    iterate(x, acc, timezone) |> t_download(interval, t_agent)
  end)
  acc |> Calendar.DateTime.to_erl |> Calendar.DateTime.from_erl(timezone, {123456, 6}) |> ambiguous_handle |> Calendar.DateTime.add!(86400)
end)
```

it's basically doing a loop around `total_days`.

The value of a schedule is a full week. such as.

```
{"Monday":["00:00-23:59"],"Tuesday":["00:00-23:59"],"Wednesday":["00:00-23:59"],"Thursday":["00:00-23:59"],"Friday":["00:00-23:59"],"Saturday":["00:00-23:59"],"Sunday":["00:00-23:59"]}
```

other methods are such as..

```
  defp ambiguous_handle(value) do
    case value do
      {:ok, datetime} -> datetime
      {:ambiguous, datetime} -> datetime.possible_date_times |> hd
    end
  end

  defp get_head_tail([]), do: []
  defp get_head_tail(nil), do: []
  defp get_head_tail([head|tail]) do
    [[head]|get_head_tail(tail)]
  end

  def t_download([], _interval, _t_agent), do: :noop
  def t_download([starting, ending], interval, t_agent) do
    t_do_loop(starting, ending, interval, t_agent)
  end

  defp t_do_loop(starting, ending, _interval, _t_agent) when starting >= ending, do: :noop
  defp t_do_loop(starting, ending, interval, t_agent) do
    Agent.update(t_agent, fn list -> ["true" | list] end)
    t_do_loop(starting + interval, ending, interval, t_agent)
  end

  def download([], _camera_exid, _interval, _id, _requestor), do: :noop
  def download([starting, ending], camera_exid, interval, id, requestor) do
    do_loop(starting, ending, interval, camera_exid, id, requestor)
  end
```

I am actually using an Agent to count how many times loop pas through the `download`, It's working totally fine and giving me the results as well.

My question is that, is this a proper way of doing it? I am just updating Agent's value. and in the end, I count the total list of true values.

But I am looking for a more simple or solid solution. The Iteration will go around all those methods each time. I am running it twice.

First to do the actual operation to download pictures and then to count possible counts, how many pictures could be downloaded.

```
  def iterate([], _check_time, _timezone), do: []
  def iterate([head], check_time, timezone) do
    [from, to] = String.split head, "-"
    [from_hour, from_minute] = String.split from, ":"
    [to_hour, to_minute] = String.split to, ":"

    from_unix_timestamp = unix_timestamp(from_hour, from_minute, check_time, timezone)
    to_unix_timestamp = unix_timestamp(to_hour, to_minute, check_time, timezone)
    [from_unix_timestamp, to_unix_timestamp]
  end
```

The whole above process is actually, taking schedule value. with each day by day. and with a starting and ending time. And Loop it through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the accumulator in the main loop to collect both dates *and* counts with a help of [`Enum.sum/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#sum/1):

```rb
Enum.reduce(1..total_days, {start_date, 0}, fn _i, {dates, counts} ->
  day_of_week = Calendar.Date.day_of_week_name(dates)
  more_counts =
    schedule[day_of_week]
    |> get_head_tail()
    |> Enum.map(fn(x) ->
      x
      |> iterate(dates, timezone)
      |> t_download(interval, t_agent)
    end)
    |> Enum.sum()
  dates =
    dates
    |> Calendar.DateTime.to_erl()
    |> Calendar.DateTime.from_erl(timezone, {123456, 6})
    |> ambiguous_handle()
    |> Calendar.DateTime.add!(86400)

  {dates, more_counts + counts}
end)
```

The following methods should be updated to pass the number through.

```rb
def t_download(start_end, interval, agent, acc \\ 0)
def t_download([], _interval, _t_agent, acc), do: acc
def t_download([starting, ending], interval, t_agent, acc) do
  t_do_loop(starting, ending, interval, t_agent, acc)
end

defp t_do_loop(starting, ending, _interval, _t_agent, acc) when starting >= ending, do: acc
defp t_do_loop(starting, ending, interval, t_agent, acc) do
  t_do_loop(starting + interval, ending, interval, t_agent, acc + 1)
end
```

The above would return a tuple with dates as the first element (what your implementation returned before) *and* counts as the second element.

Comment: Do you mean count for each day? like then we can plus all the counts with tuples?

Comment: The code above already sums everything up. Check the acc returned.

Comment: also in line `|> iterate(acc, timezone)` where the acc coming from?

Comment: It’s a leftover, sorry, fixed.

Comment: Okay, I put the start date as `2019-07-01T00:00:00+05:00` and end dates as `2019-07-05T00:00:00+05:00` so total days are 5. and the method returned me only this

`{#DateTime<2019-07-06 00:00:00.123456+01:00 IST Europe/Dublin>, 0}`

Comment: whereas the method in question agents return 10 true's

Comment: Ah, indeed, `t_do_loop` recursively always end up with returning `:noop`, so it also should be tweaked to return a number instead. This number might be collected passing the accumulator through. You have asked about the proper way to do it; the proper ways is to collect the number, not to have a redundant process. I will update the answer.